# Как можно получить цвет созданной кисти?

Tags: c++, winapi

Как можно получить цвет созданной кисти?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию [GetObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```cpp
HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(128, 127, 126)); // создаём кисть

LOGBRUSH logBrush;                                    // объект, который хранит информацию о hBrush
GetObject(hBrush, sizeof(LOGBRUSH), &logBrush);       // получаем logBrush

COLORREF color = logBrush.lbColor;                    // берём цвет
cout << (int)GetRValue(color) << ' ' 
     << (int)GetGValue(color) << ' ' 
     << (int)GetBValue(color) << endl;
// 128 127 126
```